# Can't render children (let alone routed children) inside routed react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Building my first React app and I am trying to create a nested router within the authenticated 'internal' page but it's proving quite difficult. I've tried a number of things, but this is the latest incarnation--and I am getting a `cannot read 'children' property of undefined` error in the AuthenticatedFrame component.

```
export class NavigationFrame extends React.Component<INavigationFrameProps, {}> {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log(this.props.store.store.getState())
        return <Router>
                  <div className="navigation-frame">
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Splash}/>
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationForm}/>
                  <Route path="/signin" component={SignInContainer}/>
                  <Route path="/i" render={() => (
                        this.props.store.store.getState().authenticationState.authenticated ? (
                            <AuthenticatedFrame>
                                <Route exact path="/i/" component={WelcomePage}/>
                                <Route path="/i/add" component={AddPage}/>
                            </AuthenticatedFrame>
                        ) : (
                            <Redirect to="/signin"/>
                        )
                        )}/>
                  </div>
               </Router>;
    }
}
```

And my AuthenticatedFrame (doesn't work)

```
export const AuthenticatedFrame = () => (
    <div className="internal-view">
    <SidebarDrawer />
    <div className="content-area">
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
    </div>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthenticatedFrame` is a functional component and hence doesn't have access to `this` keyword, you need to access props as function arguments like

```
export const AuthenticatedFrame = (props) => (
    <div className="internal-view">
       <SidebarDrawer />
       <div className="content-area">
          {props.children}
       </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Urf. I just had to change out Authenticated Frame with this:

```
export class AuthenticatedFrame extends React.Component<{children: any}, {}> {
    render() { return <div className="internal-view">
    <SidebarDrawer />
    <div className="content-area">
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
    </div>}
```